# Differences between sunspot and tire gems

Tags: solr, thinking-sphinx, sunspot, elasticsearch, tire

Currently I am using [thinking sphinx](http://ts.freelancing-gods.com) for search. Now I'm considering using [sunspot](http://sunspot.github.com/) or [tire](http://karmi.github.com/tire/) because they automatically index new content.

Are there any performance differences between the two? Is there anything else I should be concerned with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the first difference is that you want to decide which search engine you think is best for your purposes: SOLR or Elasticsearch. We're using SOLR via Sunspot right now, but we're thinking seriously about moving to Elasticsearch because it feels like a better match for the sorts of web app functionality we want. It was incredibly easy to set up Tire, install the attachments plugin, and get search operating against data both in the database and in PDF attachments, with highlighting (now working thanks to another answer here on SO). Also, from a development/debugging point of view being able to use curl to test queries and see results is just great.

From the point of view of coding in a Rails app, you're right that both Sunspot and Tire are very similar. They both use the idea of a searchable/mapping block that defines what fields to index and how, and then performing a search is quite similar. As far as performance goes, I might give a bit of advantage to Tire, partly because the way it paginates and indexes in bulk is pretty slick (via the rake tire:import task). The ability in tire to control the indexing contents via to_json is very flexible as well.

Ultimately I think probably Sunspot and Tire are close enough that the choice between SOLR vs Elasticsearch is where you'll really end up making your decision.